# App crash on access new Database

Tags: c++, symbian

My application crashes on reading / writing data from the database. I have one database on c: and I copy-pasted and rename with different name.  The following process is what I have used for copy...Please guide me if you have any suggestion or solution.

```
RFs fs;
fs.Connect();

CFileMan* fileMan=CFileMan::NewL(fs);
CleanupStack::PushL(fileMan);

TInt err=fileMan->Copy(anOld,aNew);

CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(fileMan);
fs.Close();

if(err==KErrNone)
return ETrue;
else
return EFalse;
```

It crashes on following line when I am trying to insert or get any data from the database.

```
User::LeaveIfError( iDatabase.Execute( strSQL ) );
```

### db creation:

```
TBool Open = OpenL();

if (!Open)
{

User::LeaveIfError(iDbSession.Connect());

CleanupClosePushL(iDbSession);
CleanupClosePushL(iDatabase);

User::LeaveIfError(iDatabase.Replace(iDbSession, iDBPath ));

// create table
_LIT(KSQLtest,"CREATE TABLE testtable(id INTEGER,test1 VARCHAR(50),test2 VARCHAR(50))"); User::LeaveIfError(iDatabase.Execute(KSQLtest));

iDatabase.Compact();
iDatabase.Close();
iDbSession.Close();
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();
```

### Open database:

```
User::LeaveIfError( iDbSession.Connect() );

CleanupClosePushL( iDbSession );

if ( KErrNone != iDatabase.Open(iDbSession, iDBPath))
{
iDbSession.Close();
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();
return EFalse;
}
else
{
CleanupClosePushL( iDatabase );
iIsDatabaseOpened = ETrue;
return ETrue;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post so the code is readable.

Answer (score 1):

`User:: LeaveIfError()` throws an exception when `iDatabase.Execute()` returns an error code.

You can find the most common Symbian error codes at [NewLC](http://www.newlc.com/en/Symbian-OS-Error-Codes.html)

If the crash happens before `RDbDatabase::Execute()` is actually run, we'll need to see more code to figure out why `iDatabase` is in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what "crashes" means - an exception/leave? a panic? If so, what leave code, or what panic category and number?

If it "crashes" here

```
User::LeaveIfError( iDatabase.Execute( strSQL ) );
```

you might want to check the return value, i.e.

```
TInt error = iDatabase.Execute( strSQL );
//Now log/display the error
User::LeaveIfError(error);
```

A few other points of note:

- If you use `CleanupClosePushL()` on an object, you don't need to call both `Close()` and `CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy()`. The latter will call `Close()` for you.
- Your `OpenL()` function uses a mix of leaving and return code which is considered bad style generally. In addition, functions which leave something on the cleanup stack are generally named `xxxxLC()`, the trailing 'C' denoting a cleanup item.